# Just created a Git repo on my computer. How to get the repo onto GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git.  I just created a Git repository on my computer.  Now I would like to connect that repository to the website (GitHub) and push my code there.

How do I do this?  I am somewhat familiar...I have to somehow set the online code to be upstream or downstream of my pc version, and then do a commit or push or pull to the upstream or downstream online version...

And I need to push or pull it to GitHub with Pycharm...
(but from the Git command line is fine...)

Comment: What do you mean *"onto git"*? *Which* website? GitHub? Bitbucket? Both have step-by-step guides, as I'd imagine any others would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by not making assumptions about where you're remote (that's the word!) is.

**Here are some steps I think you've already completed**

In (a) Terminal:

```
cd "/path/name/to/repo/folder" # this folder should/ can contain all of your files and folders for the project
git init # initialize the repository
git add * # add everything (the * is like in a reg ex)
git commit -m "have to make a first commit"
```

**Maybe what you're looking for**

```
git remote add origin https://example.com/userName/repoName
git push -u origin master
```

So the userName would be something like "bordeo". "site.com" might be "github.com".

Go to GitHub.com, e.g., and create that repo. Then copy the link and insert it after the `git remote add origin`.

---

If by chance you actually wanted to *clone* a remote repo (i.e., it already existed on GitHub, and you want it on your local machine, and to get your local machine set up to push to GitHub), then you can do the following:

Change your directory (using `cd`) to the folder that will *contain* the repository folder (so if you want `foo/MyRepo`, `cd` to `foo`, the `MyRepo` folder will be created in the next command), then do `git clone https://github.com/userName/MyRepo`.

Comment: I posted this answer before the Pycharm edit. that piece is beyond me. But my suggestion is fairly general, hopefully still helpful

Comment: I ran that, did an initial commit, then ran `git push -u origin master` and got the following error: "src refspec master does not match any."

Comment: Did you `git remote add origin ...` etc ? Where did the error pop up, just after that last line?

Comment: Also, what happens if you type `git remote`, and then if you type `git remote origin show`?

Comment: Simply, the URL should match the results of `git config --get remote.origin.url`

Comment: 1) `git remote add ...` 2) `git commit -m 'initialize'` 3) `git push -u origin master` 4) "src refspec...etc"

Comment: `git remote origin show` = "Error: unknown subcommand origin"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97091/discussion-between-rbatt-and-bordeo).

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption you (a) mean GitHub (b) just ran `git init` in the directory you want to upload.

Head over to https://github.com/new to build the upstream repo. Then GitHub gives you directions, like these ones for a repository called "blah:"

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/mjb/blah.git
git push -u origin master
```