# merging local repo with github repo is resulting in a fatal error

Tags: git, github

I'm using git version 2.16.2. I have a repo locally and created a new repo on github to take the files I already created locally. I have done:

```
git init
git add origin https://github.com/me/repo
```

Then (after I commit) I go to push:

```
git push origin master
```

and I get:

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/me/repo
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

[I found this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111474/just-created-a-git-repo-on-my-computer-how-to-get-the-repo-onto-github) and so I ran:

```
$ git pull
```

Which gives:

```
From https://github.com/me/repo
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

So I go to push again, and I get:

```
$ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/r-wells/react-fun
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Then I realize I didn't pull `master` so i run:

```
$ git pull https://github.com/me/repo master
```

But I get:

```
From https://github.com/r-wells/react-fun
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I was under the impression that `$ git pull` would integrate the remote changes. I'm assuming I'm missing something small. Anyone see something I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors tell that your local branch is behind from master.

`Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`

1) Try `git pull origin master --rebase`

if it does not work then local and remote branch, not in sync.
you have to first sync your local master branch with remote master.

**follow following steps:**

1. copy your new commit hash which you recently commit.
2. run `git fetch origin`
3. run `git reset --hard origin/master` # to sync your
   local master with remoter master
4. cherry-pick your commit: `git cherry-pick your_commit_hash`
5. `git push origin master` # to push your commit
   Let me know if it still not resolved.

Thanks!

Comment: Rebase worked, there was a conflict in the README.md file, I edited that to reflect all current changes The did rebase —continue. Thanks!!